# What is the round v symbol used by my thermodynamics text for volume and specific volume?

Tags: symbols, letters

The shape is somewhere between a v and a u. I'm almost certain it's a letter character as they have both lower and uppercase (used for specific and total volume respectively).

Since the v and V characters are also used for things like voltage and velocity, it's important for me to be able to distinguish these.

The top six symbols below are what I want, the first four being lowercase and the next two being uppercase.

[image: photo of the symbols list in the front of my textbook]

Comment: Isn't it just the greek letter `\nu`?

Comment: @daleif, I don't know anything about thermodynamics, but the capital \nu is just N...  don't know if that's the character the OP wanted?

Comment: maybe it's possible to post an example of the capital character, too?

Comment: It's definitely not `\nu`. The nomenclature section of the textbook lists the greek letter symbols separately. `\nu` is used for the "stoichiometric coefficient".

Comment: Isn't it a "v"?

Comment: I changed the image. Now it shows what normal V looks like, as well as the capital.

Comment: the important distinction seems to be between serif (for voltage and velocity) and sans serif (for volume).  the rounded shape adds some distinction, but the serif/sans distinction seems more important to me.

Comment: during my study the specific volume was symbolized by the greek letter `\nu`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_volume

Comment: @daleif -- the shape confusion arises from the similarity between the pointy "v" and the "nu" in many fonts.  for this reason, competent math fonts have always substituted a rounded "v" in fonts (like times) where the usual italic "v" is pointy.  (in the case of times, it's my understanding that the round "v" from century schoolbook was the substitution.)  most font designers simply never had to deal with math.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- not a `\nu`; wikipedia is either wrong or using "bad" fonts.  see my comment to daleif.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much to my surprise, [WhattheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/itc-benguiat-gothic/) found the pretty close match and this is the result from ITC Benguiat Gothic.

[image]

I have to put a disclaimer here that I'm quite surprised that the inner join is left like that. And the designer is a famous font designer so either I have zero taste or else....

As I've commented (and deleted for this answer) it looks like a two-path TikZ picture with `round cap`. So... yeah...

Comment: That is so random. I mean, I appreciate their effort in distinguishing the various Vs, but it's very confusing.

Comment: Anyway, I take it there's no way to just use this character in my LaTeX equations in Anki decks... I guess since they're for my own purposes I'll just use an accent or something.

Comment: The link says "Page Not Found" now. Can you fix it please?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It's a `\nu`. There might be differences in the nomenclature, but if I recall correctly, `\nu` is the variable for the specific volume.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_volume

http://books.google.de/books?id=FR2gVgjj3EEC&lpg=PR22&ots=zg33bG3I7F&dq=%22critical%20specific%20volume%22&hl=de&pg=PR22#v=onepage&q=%22critical%20specific%20volume%22&f=false

Edit:

Whatthefont.com says the letter is a capital `V` from the typeface [ITC Benguiat Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/itc-benguiat-gothic/book-oblique/).

Comment: It's not a `\nu` you can compare the left branches of both.

Comment: The only option left is `\vee`, but that doesn't quite fit either. So I stay with `\nu`.

Comment: @percusse I can confirm that the right symbol for the specific volume is `\nu` and the symbol for the volume is a capital `V` (in thermodynamics). Probably the author didn't know how to dinstinguish different quantities and used those symbols (it seems a MS Word document)

Comment: @karlkoeller I can confirm that too but the character is not `\nu`.

Comment: so the proper character to use is \nu, but alas, that's not the symbol the OP is asking for?

Comment: it is definitely *not* a `\nu`; see the nist document [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf), p.28, section 8.6.9.  the symbols are cap V (total volume) and lowercase v (specific volume), both italic.  (it's traditional to use the same letter, cap and lowercase, to represent closely related concepts.)  since there's a conflict with voltage (bold upright V) and velocity (cap italic V) in the document used as a reference in the initial question, i think the choice of italic sans v and V is a good one.

Comment: Yeah, no matter who might use `\nu` for specific volume, I want to be able to make that symbol in my Anki decks. Which is definitely not `\nu`. Thanks though.